# Android RotateAnimation bug

Tags: android, rotateanimation

I have a `RotateAnimation` attached to an `ImageButton` which upon click rotates it and using `OnAnimationEnd` starts a new Activity.

Problem is its not working. After I close my application and come back, I am inside the `new Activity(..)` and when I go back, then the animation executes. I want the animation to happen and then start the new Activity.

For some reason, it was working absolutely fine before using the same code but I don't know, some trivial change may have affected it.

Here's the code

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);         
     setContentView(R.layout.menu);
    ImageButton amazingPicsButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.amazingPics),              
   setViewOnClick(amazingPicsButton, new Intent("com.jasfiddle.AmazingInterface.AMAZINGPICS"));     
}
/**
 * Generic OnClick setter method for giving various View objects a click listener
 * @param b
 * @param intent
 */
private <B> void setViewOnClick(B b, final Intent intent){
    ((View) b).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            amazingPicsSound = createRandButSound();
            amazingPicsSound.start();
            rotateAndNewActivity(v, intent);

        }
    });         

}


/** function that produces rotation animation on the View v.
 * Could be applied to button, ImageView, ImageButton, etc.
 */
private void rotateAndNewActivity(View v, final Intent intent){
    // Create an animation instance
    Animation an = new RotateAnimation(30, 360, v.getWidth()/2, v.getHeight()/2);
    an.setDuration(50);               // duration in ms
    an.setRepeatCount(3);                // -1 = infinite repeate

    /*we override the Animation an object to include the start of an new Activity
    at the end of animation */
     an.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener(){
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
        }

        //start the activity onAnimationEnd
        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            startActivity(intent);
        }       
     });
    // Set the animation's parameters


    v.setAnimation(an);

}
```

Comment: Try `v.startAnimation(an);` instead of `v.setAnimation(an);`

Comment: Please post this as an answer so I can accept, upvote and thank you :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`setAnimation`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setAnimation%28android.view.animation.Animation%29) only sets the next animation to play on the [`View`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html). To start an animation immediately, use [`startAnimation`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#startAnimation%28android.view.animation.Animation%29)

In your case, use `v.startAnimation(an);`